# Customise Google Bar Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I currently use the below code to visualise a dataset of locations and times (measured by subtracting two epoch times, ie milliseconds) using Google Charts. However, I wish to give the user the option to view the chart at different scales ie. in milliseconds, seconds or minutes. How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
 <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">

 <title>Google Graph and CSV</title>
 <meta name="description" content="test">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> // load the visualisation API
  google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });
</script>

<style>
#main { 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#crt_ertdlyYY    {
    width: 50%px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#outsidePie  {
    width: 600px;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function drawVisualization() {
   $.get("bg_extracted_times.csv", function(csvString) {
        var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
        var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
            data,
            [{
                column: 0,
                modifier: function (value) {
                    return value.toLowerCase();
                },
                type: 'string',
                label: 'Location'
            }],
            [{
                column: 1,
                aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
                type: 'number',
                label: 'Time (secconds)'
            }]
        );
      var crt_ertdlyYY = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: 'BarChart',
         containerId: 'crt_ertdlyYY',
         dataTable: aggData,
         options:{
            title: 'Room Occupancy for 20:82:c0:d9:6c:4b',
            titleTextStyle : {color: 'grey', fontSize: 16},
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            width:600,
            height:600,
            pieStartAngle: 0,
            is3D: true,
            legend:false,
         }
      });
      crt_ertdlyYY.draw();
   });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)
</script>

<div id="main">
<div id="crt_ertdlyYY"></div>
<div id="outsidePie"></div>
</div>
```

I am hoping to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJPfW.png) where the options are minutes, secconds or millisecconds.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a custom `aggregation` function to return the desired scale

**assuming the current column from the csv represents milliseconds**

it is easy to convert to *seconds* by dividing by `1000`
or *minutes* via dividing by `(1000 * 60)`

you can add a column for each to `aggData`...

```
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,
  [{
    column: 0,
    modifier: function (value) {
      return value.toLowerCase();
    },
    type: 'string'
  }],
  [
    {
      column: 1,
      aggregation: getSeconds,  // <-- seconds
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Total (Seconds)'
    },
    {
      column: 1,
      aggregation: getMinutes,  // <-- minutes
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Total (Minutes)'
    }
  ]
);

function getSeconds(values) {
  var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function (value) {
    sum += value;
  });
  return sum / 1000;
}

function getMinutes(values) {
  var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function (value) {
    sum += value;
  });
  return sum / (1000 * 60);
}
```

then use a `DataView` to display the column selected by the user...

```
// create view over aggData
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(aggData);

// view with seconds
view.setColumns([0, 1]);

// or view with minutes
view.setColumns([0, 2]);
```

**ALSO**

need to use new library...
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will *only* change the `load` statement, from...
`google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });`

to...
`google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });`

and you can add the `callback` directly to the `load` statement

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

Comment: Where do I put the DataView?

Comment: use it on the chart, in place of `aggData`

Comment: Also, I think in the first block your column for displaying the minutes should be two, however I am unable to edit it.

Comment: Whenever I try to run the getSecconds and getMinutes functions I get thrown syntax errors about missing brackets, but I can't see any mistakes. Any idea?

Comment: sorry, the word 'function' in the argument for each `forEach` was mis-spelled -- as for column reference 2, there are only two columns in the source data, the source column for both `getSeconds` and `getMinutes` should be 1